# "bash --noprofile --norc" destroys .bash_history

Tags: command-line, bash, history

While I have `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTSIZE` greater than 500, the bash history gets destroyed after I entered to a "norc" shell. How can I keep the history data through the various shell types?

Here's an actual example.

```sh
// on the normal shell (bash)
/mnt/c/pg$ wc ~/.bash_history
  876  1997 19855 /home/user/.bash_history

/mnt/c/pg$ logout

PS > bash --noprofile --norc

// on the norc shell
bash-4.4$ wc ~/.bash_history
  847  1947 19406 /home/user/.bash_history
// -> notice that .bash_history is trimmed to the default 500 lines. This is the problem.

bash-4.4$ exit

// again on the normal shell
PS > bash

/mnt/c/pg$ wc ~/.bash_history
  848  1948 19439 /home/user/.bash_history
// -> once I enter to a norc shell, it affects the entire shell experiences
```

Here's a part of my .bashrc and .profile

```
// .bashrc

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it

// ..
```

```
// .profile

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  # no duplicate entries
export HISTSIZE=100000                   # big big history
export HISTFILESIZE=100000               # big big history
shopt -s histappend                      # append to history, don't overwrite it

// ..
```

Comment: Maybe instead of using `--norc`, use `--rcfile` with a file containing just these options? Or set `HISTFILE` to some non-default path, say `~/.histfile` instead of `~/.bash_history`, then the `--norc` shell will use the default path and leave your actual history alone.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with empty `HISTFILE`, so the shell will not try to update the default file:

```
HISTFILE= bash --noprofile --norc
```